# Sending Email using Amazon SES service under Amazon VPC

Tags: java, amazon-ses

I have 2 instance under VPC. In that one instance has internet access and another has not. I want to use Amazon SES(Simple Email Service) in interntless instance. I have tried to send mail but it fails to send. I want to know that Can I send email using Amazon SES from My VPC without InternetAccess in VPC? I am following [this example](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=219328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send Email from VPC we have to configure amazon vpc as per this [docs](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/vpc/). There must have internet connection to send email through AWS SES.